# Is there a way to stop go code compiling with older versions of go?

Tags: go

We have some internal command line tools written in Go, and we're using the vendor folder to control their dependencies.

However, if the tools are updated with `go get` using Go 1.4 or lower (or 1.5 without the vendor experiment flag), from what I understand the dependencies will be pulled separately into the gopath.

Is there a way to require a minimum version of the go compiler to compile a package, so we have a hard and fast way to ensure everyone has the minimum version we expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this [in rclone](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/blob/master/versioncheck.go)
 with a build constraint like this.  All go compilers version >= 1.5 will set the `go1.5` build constraint so this won't build with a compiler < 1.5 and will build with a compiler >= 1.5.

```
//+build !go1.5

package main

// Upgrade to Go version 1.5 to compile rclone.
func init() { Go_version_1_5_required_for_compilation() }
```